# Does "none the more..." mean "far from (being)..." in American English?

Tags: idioms, american-english, word-usage

I'm familiar with the somewhat colloquial turn of phrase  "nowhere near as ... as" / "not anywhere near as ... as" to say "far from being as ... as".

However, I'm *a little* less familiar with the idiom "none the more …" meaning, I gather, "far ... from being".

And so, I wish someone would tell me whether the expression "none the more ..." is safe to use interchangeably with "far from ..." in formal and not so informal contexts, or definitely belongs to informal, colloquial usage and, as such, should be best avoided in formal style.

E.g.:

> They only half believed us and were **none the more** friendly... [[source]](http://books.google.fr/books?id=T4B9KP_I0bMC&pg=PA99&lpg=PA99&dq=%22none+the+more+friendly%22&source=bl&ots=gUMORMIF3F&sig=5u3MqVpAH-hL6GHU74N7kpxabtk&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=POz8UsG8CY6a0QWP74CgCQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22none%20the%20more%20friendly%22&f=false)
>
> ... to my taste, it was **none the more** becoming for being fitted over broken stayed-bones... [[source]](http://www.ebooksread.com/authors-eng/bernard-edward-joseph-capes/the-extraordinary-confessions-of-diana-please-goo/page-5-the-extraordinary-confessions-of-diana-please-goo.shtml)
>
> ... the individual returns home poorer and **none the healthier**. [[source]](http://www.stetzerizer-us.com/The-Health-Effects-of-Electrical-Pollution_df_68.html)

Comment: Notice that 'more' is a comparative form. It is necessary to have a comparator: They _only half believed us_ and _were none the more friendly_ (ie they were not more than 'half-friendly'!) (better, as you imply, read as 'far from being friendly'). One uses 'far from being' as a quantifier without any need for a comparator.

Comment: @Edwin: I'm not sure that's strictly true. You're entitled to your opinion, nonetheless. But what exactly does the comparator *less* reference there?

Comment: There must be a comparator. After checking the context in OP's link, it is probably _They only half believed us and were none the more friendly [than they would have been had our clothing not been so obviously hard-used']. (It _would_ be nice to be provided with sufficient context.) // Do I need to point out that it's "a little less familiar with the idiom Z than with W and W' " (though not put grammatically)? OP's later example has 'than it was / would have been' as the implied comparator.

Comment: @Edwin: there is indeed a comparator, but I think you've identified the wrong one. The original is *"You are Germans?" they asked politely. So we said "Of course not." … They only half believed us, and were none the more friendly for that.* So they weren't any friendlier to them than they would have been to Germans which, considering this is during World War II, is presumably not very friendly at all.

Comment: I take it as "they were not particularly friendly to us even though they thought it possible we weren't Germans".

Comment: @Peter: I see you're right about the context there. I must admit there's something decidedly "awkward" about the amount of comparing/contrasting going on there. My first thought was it would flow more smoothly is "and" were replaced by "but" - except then it seems you'd also have to delete the word "only" to remain even *close* to the original sense. But in the end, I think if I'd been writing it that's what I'd have done (and added "all" before "that") - even if it changed the nuance slightly, at least it should be easier for the reader to follow.

Comment: @Peter Yes. A little context is a dangerous thing. None at all is lethal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that it is the idiom "[none the wiser](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/be-none-the-wiser)" that you are thinking of. This means

> to still be confused about something even after it has been explained
>   to you

I would then surmise that the authors of the sources you have given have simply substituted other adjectives into this saying.

This [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=none%20the%20wiser,none%20the%20richer,none%20the%20healthier&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,none%20the%20wiser;,c0;.t1;,none%20the%20richer;,c0;.t1;,none%20the%20healthier;,c0) shows that "none the wiser" has been used significantly more than "none the richer" or "none the healthier", but that "none the richer" actually predates "none the wiser" in print. I can't speak for whether "none the + comparative" was once a standard form, but certainly it only really caught on with "wiser".

[image]

Nonetheless, with reference to the common idiom, we can assume that these other uses mean "still not [something], even after [something]."

Your third quote, in context, supports this:

> it is clear that the medical establishment was unable to help their
>   condition and after expensive tests and manifold prescriptions, the
>   individual returns home poorer and none the healthier

That is, they are still not healthy, despite having sought treatment at a medical establishment.

With an adjective that takes "more" in the comparative, rather than an -er ending, we would of course then have "none the more", eg, "none the more beautiful".

To address your queries: it is not the same meaning as "far from", and is nonstandard outside of the idiomatic "none the wiser"; as such, it is best used in informal contexts.

Comment: +1 I had similar thoughts. The general form is *none the...* as you say. *None the more* shouldn't be conflated with *nonetheless*. For example "Great as are our privileges, we are none the more safe" http://www.glottopedia.org/index.php/Dative_alternation This in no way can be taken to mean "higher privileges make one nevertheless more safe", as *nevertheless* would imply something that contradicts expectations.

Comment: Yes, and it should not be taken as the *opposite* of "nonetheless" either! I'm actually having trouble figuring out whether your example means "still not safe despite our great privileges" or something else.. I think it's "more safe" that's throwing me.

Comment: I think we're on the same page. Another way to say it is "not any safer (none the more safe) despite our greater privileges".

Comment: Good point about "not any"! I would just expect "none the safer" over "none the more safe".

Answer (score 1):

Comparatively speaking, *none the more* is [virtually non-existent](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=were%20none%20the%20more,were%20none%20the%20less&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,were%20none%20the%20more;,c0;.t1;,were%20none%20the%20less;,c0)...

[image]

I would say that OP's cited usage (from about 70 years ago) is highly likely to be misinterpreted by the modern reader. What it actually means is they weren't very friendly to start with, and the fact that they were suspicious certainly didn't help. But I (and probably many other readers) could easily mistake an exceptionally uncommon usage for a very common one with a completely opposite sense.

Nonetheless, it's also worth pointing out [just how comparatively uncommon both forms are](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=were%20none%20the%20more,were%20none%20the%20less,nonetheless&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,were%20none%20the%20more;,c0;.t1;,were%20none%20the%20less;,c0;.t1;,nonetheless;,c0)...

[image]

That's to say, for the best part of a century, nearly everyone has used the single-word form for the [common idiom](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/nonetheless). But I doubt there would be *any* single-word instances of OP's already-rare term.